# Executing a sequence in Liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

How can I execute a sequence in Liquibase? I tried valueComputed="TAB.NEXTVAL" but it doesn't work and I get a message that TAB_ID cannot be NULL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

<changeSet author="Me" id="sql-example">  
       <comment>My comment</comment>  
       <insert tableName="TAB_WITH_FILE" dbms="oracle">
             <column name="TAB_ID" valueComputed="TAB.NEXTVAL"/>
             <column name="TAB_FILE_NAME">Desert.jpg</column>
             <column name="TAB_FILE" valueBlobFile="files/Desert.jpg"/>
       </insert>
</changeSet>    

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: What i sthe Liquibase version? Can you share the chengeSet or statement you used to create the sequence?

Comment: I use version 3.5.3. I try set up liquibase to my existing old program. I used sql script to update but now I want to use  liquibase. When I used sql script I created sequence: CREATE SEQUENCE TAB
  START WITH 50
  INCREMENT BY 50
          ;

Comment: btw there's no PL/SQL here.